# How to use a friend function in cpp file?

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

I have a header file and a cpp file... In the .h file I declared a `ZZZ` class and added some private parameters and declared a `friend` function but when I try to access the private parametrs in the .cpp file I get an error:

```
error: within this context
     output << zzz.ZZZ_name << "." ;
```

And I get also in the heder file this error with the private parametrs:

```
error: 'std::string X::Y::ZZZ::ZZZ_name' is private
     string ZZZ_name;
```

**ZZZ.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

namespace X {
namespace Y {

class ZZZ {
private:
    string ZZZ_name;

public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ZZZ &zzz);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ZZZ &zzz);

}}
```

**ZZZ.cpp**

```
#include "ZZZ.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

using namespace X::Y;
using std::cout;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ZZZ& zzz){
    output << zzz.ZZZ_name << "." ;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: The header references namespaces `X` and `Y`. The `.cpp` file inexplicably references completely different namespaces named `x` and `y`. This is obviously not real code, but fantasy code (not to mention the obvious syntax error in the header file with the missing closing parenthesis in the function declaration). If you would like to get helpful answers with problems with real code, you need to show real code, in the form of a [mcve], instead of wasting everyone's time with fake code. Fail.

Comment: will i am not waisting your time beecause i didn't ask you :) also my code is very big and i wanted to aske about this specific thing .. and i know no one would help me if i insert a 1000+ code .. the idea is very clear : how to declare a friend function an cpp

Comment: @kasandra Did you compile this sample code though? godbolt points out both the missing parenthesis and the incorrect namespace before it complains about the operator.

Comment: someone already helped me without complaining because he knows i asked about an idea how to

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you're saying. Instead of providing a [mcve] with real code, as this help center article explains; you are expecting someone to read made-up code that has nothing to do with anything, with obvious typos in addition to the real problem, whatever it is, and figure it out for you? There are plenty of other questions here where the asker took the time to prune down their large code to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue, and someone gave an answer. If you don't care to put some effort in asking a good question, getting a good answer will be unlikely.

Comment: @kasandra _"someone already helped me"_ That doesn't make your question better.

Comment: okkk soryyyyyyy learned my lesson .

Comment: i actually searched a lot before asking , and i apoligized aslo i can't remove the question since it has an answer .. i tried but didn't work.,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because you are declared your friend function inside namespaces `X` and `Y`, you have to tell the compiler that your definition in the source file belongs to the already declared prototype:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ZZZ& zzz);
```

So, to resolve ambiguity that your definition is not a new function without a forward declaration, you have to prefix it with namespaces inside the source file:

```
std::ostream& X::Y::operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ZZZ& zzz) {
    output << zzz.ZZZ_name << "." ;
    return output;
}
```

Or, as another option, you can do the following as well:

```
namespace X { namespace Y {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const ZZZ& zzz) {
        output << zzz.ZZZ_name << "." ;
        return output;
    }
}}
```

Comment: i can't i n my case ! the professer asked not to :\

Comment: it is not me :\ i actually accespted you answer